# Can we create Server in desktop application using SignalR?

Tags: c#, signalr

I need to develop desktop application as a Server using SignalR. I want to know SignalR is only for ASP.net webapplication or it can be used as Desktop application?

**On SignalR client side**, SignalR provides client libraries for .NET, JavaScript, Silverlight, Windows Phone, Windows RT and even iOS and Android through Xamarin.

**On server side**, can we make Server in desktop application using SignalR? SignalR possible in visual studio 2010 or higher version?

Comment: Yes it's possible with self hosting. Please see the tutorial on: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host. But I'm afraid you need Visual Studio 2012 or higher.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

What you are searching for is named "SignalR Self-Host"

Tutorial from Microsoft:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host

Tip:
Use Win8 or Win2012 for the host for WebSocket support.